# Resizing UIView frame rect, do the sublayers resize?

Tags: objective-c

I have a UIView and I change the frame size but I dont think the layer is resizing. How does one resize the layer with the frame without overriding layoutSubviews?

Comment: Do you mean the subviews? They don't resize with the parent view.

Comment: No, I have sublayers in a subclassed UIButton but layoutSubview overidding brings the layer back up the z order and then covers the other subviews.